# PHP: send html email from microsoft exchange server 2007

Tags: php, exchange-server-2007

I can't send e-mail to outside of my domain using basic php mail function.It shows error when i want to send e-mail to yahoo or gmail or outside of my domain.The error is:**Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay in C:\-----\email.php on line 6**.My code is below.

```
 $to = "testabc@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
```

My e-mail server is Microsoft exchange server 2007.
Is their any well stablished php class or code available to send email.

pls help

Answer (score 1):

That's a server configuration issue, it doesn't have anything to do with how you send emails. Apparently relaying is not allowed, and thus you are unable to send mails to external email addresses. So either change the "to" address to one that is allowed, use another SMTP server to send the mails or change the configuration of the current one.

Comment: basically .Most of the e-mail server don't allow the relay.So,it's not possible to allow the SMTP relay on my mail server.Is their any way to do it without changing the mail server configuration??thanks for reply...

Comment: All the options are there, if you don't want to change the configuration then you'll have to use another mail server. The mail server of your ISP should be good if it doesn't require SMTP auth (otherwise you'll have to use a PHP mail library because there's no support for SMTP auth in the basic PHP mail function).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a email library like swift? http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: thanks.But lot of files their.Is their any single class to do it?

Comment: you only need to `require_once '/path/to/swift-mailer/lib/swift_required.php';` the rest of the files will be loaded automatic through the spl_autoloader

Comment: -1: problem is with MTA config - switching email abstraction layers will have no impact.